# WSL2 graphical application display issue

Tags: nvidia, graphics, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cuda, visual-artifacts

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on wsl2, Windows 11. I have installed CUDA as well. whenever I open any Ubuntu app with GUI, such as file manager or any other installed apps, the graphics window display becomes garbled or distorted. I tried switching GPU on/off, power saving on/off, and switching refresh rates, but I'm unable to fix the issue.

File manager window:

[image: file manager window]

Brave browser:

[image: brave browser]

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I also have CUDA toolkit installed. WIndows 11, AMD Radeon integrated graphics with dedicated RTX 2060 (mobile)

Comment: upvoting this question, I have the same issue. Didn't have the issue with Ubuntu 18 (on Windows 11), just installed Ubuntu 22 (from scratch), and have this problem. Tried uninstall everything and reinstall, reboot etc. Still have problem. (Nvidia Geforce 2080ti)

Comment: I don't know if @hugo's answer solved this for you, but I've read elsewhere (will update with the link if I can find it), that on WSL you do NOT want to install a real Nvidia driver. WSL comes with an Nvidia CUDA stub driver that basically just passes information to and from the host device's GPU driver. If you install CUDA Toolkit, it includes a full nvidia driver (which you *would* need if you were just running Linux directly on hardware, but you *don't* need on a VM like WSL). The solution is to either unisntall CUDA Toolkit, or manually replace its driver file w/ a copy of the stub driver

Answer (score 3):

In Power Shell

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then start again

Comment: Thanks so much.  Such a simple thing to do and I was looking at it as a complex problem.

Comment: I wish I could find this solution before reinstalling the entire WLS.. Even after reinstalling WSL and restarting Windows, the issue persisted. But, this simple solution worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated on a [post from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/18i3x0y/wsl2_gui_apps_no_longer_working_after_windows_10/), updating wsl to version 2.0.14 solves the problem (at least it solved it for me).
Before updating, it is always best to shutdown WSL doing:

```
wsl --shutdown
```